# Will a ternary operator work inside .text()?

Tags: javascript, dom

I want to append this to my DOM for every 'answer_' in my DB.

```
.append('<span>')
.text(format_date(answer_.LastModifiedDate))
```

But .LastModifiedDate won't always exist. Can I check for .LastModifiedDate in the text field? Maybe like this?

```
.append('<span>')
.text((answer_.LastModifiedDate) ? format_date(answer_.LastModifiedDate) : '')
```

Which doesn't work...

**EDIT**

I was stupidly checking for answer_.LastModifiedDate, instead of just answer.
So the following line works. Thanks for all the responses!

```
.append('<span>')
.text((answer_) ? format_date(answer_.LastModifiedDate) : '')
```

Comment: Have you tried that?  How "doesn't" it work?  What errors do you see in your console?  Also, what's `answer_`?

Comment: I suppose if `answer_` is ever `null` or `undefined`, that would cause you some trouble. Can you get results with `.text(answer_ != null && answer_.LastModifiedDate != null ? format_date(answer_.LastModifiedDate) : '')`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was stupidly checking for answer_.LastModifiedDate, instead of just answer. So the following line works. Thanks for all the responses!

```
.append('<span>')
.text((answer_) ? format_date(answer_.LastModifiedDate) : '')
```

Answer (score 2):

Of course that works. Ternary operators work anywhere you could normally place a variable. They evaluate to a value, just as if you used a string literal.

Comment: Aaaaanywhere? `var five ? 5 : 7;` Well, they work anywhere an expression is allowed. I'm just being picky.

Comment: @Cory That's what I get for not qualifying my statement.

Comment: If I want to be extremely picky, `five` in my example is a variable, and the ternary operator is not allowed, so my cruel, cruel example still holds up. Clearly I am a bad person.

Comment: Actually, in your example, five is a pointer to a variable.

Comment: I guess we should always aim for precision. So, `five` is a variable name, except that the code has invalid syntax, so there are no variables, only parser errors.

Answer (score 1):

As @FreeAsInBeer pointed out, ternary works everywhere.
The only problem with your code is that you can't just use a (maybe) non-existant value as a boolean to check whether it is defined or not; How would you check if a variable holding "false" exists?
Instead you need to check the variables type:

```
.text(typeof answer_.LastModifiedDate !== 'undefined' ? format_date(answer_.LastModifiedDate) : '')
```

Comment: Properties of objects can always be read. As long as `answer_` is not `null` or `undefined`, the `.` operator in the Daft's code should evaluate without exception.